# TypeError: state.slice is not a function (redux)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

**Function on reducer**

function that removes the selected category from the state

update added state

state={cat:[]}

```
const delCat = (state, payload) => {
  const { id } = payload
  const idx = state.category.findIndex((el) => el.id === id)
  let pastState = state.slice(0, idx)
  let futureState = state.slice(idx + 1)
  let newState = [...pastState, ...futureState]
  return {
    ...state,
    category: newState,
  }
}
```

**reducer**

```
const initialState = {
  category: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Изброное',
      color: '#5236C1',
      list: [{}]
сonst newcat = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) { 
    case 'DEL_CATEGORY':
      return delCat(state, action.payload)
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

**action**

```
export const delCat = (id) => ({
  type: 'DEL_CATEGORY',
  payload: { id },
})
```

**dispatch on file**

```
  const DelCategory = (id) => {
    dispatch(delCat(id))
  }
```

p.s. thanks in advance

Comment: can you show the state? this usally happens when the state is not an array

Comment: @liker, update code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling slice on the object instead of on the category array.

So change

```js
let pastState = state.slice(0, idx)
let futureState = state.slice(idx + 1)
```

to

```
let pastState = state.category.slice(0, idx)
let futureState = state.category.slice(idx + 1)
```

Considering that `category` is an array, you might also want to change the name to something like `categories`

Answer (score 0):

Your state is an Object. So you can't use slice method on it.

I think you meant to write this;

```
state.category.slice(0, idx)
```